# Streaming audio to PulseAudio server in Java (Windows)

Tags: java, windows, audio-streaming, pulseaudio

I want to stream audio to pulse audio server (already deployed and working pulse audio sink). On linux, I can simply use paplay command:

```
paplay --server 123.123.123.123:9000 flacaudiofile.flac
```

And its working perfect.

In Java I can run the same command in bash (Runtime.getRuntime().exec("paplay....")), but how to achieve that on Windows? There is no simple pulse audio lib, but maybe there is a way to stream audio data so pulseaudio can recognize that?

Comment: FFmpeg can output to PulseAudio, but I've never tried it with a remote server.  Perhaps there is some syntax you can use for the device name?